# Dynamically add JavaScript variable to JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to insert a JavaScript variable taken from a select drop down and place it into a JSON string.

I'm getting the variable through this:

```
var currencyFrom = $('#currency-from').find("option:selected").text().split("(")[1].replace(')', '')
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    window.universal_variable = {
        "transaction": {
            "currency": "currencyFrom",
            "currency-to": "currencyTo",
            "current-rate": "currentRate",
           }
        };
      }
   )
```

However the variable does not appear in the JSON string?

Comment: parse the JSON, update the object, and stringify it again.

Comment: That's nothing at all. An object (or json, for that matter) cannot have `=` key-value operator but `:`. This is just an invalid 'thing' and will break the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, as we said in the comments, your example is not a JSON. This is a JSON :

```
var myJson = {
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : {
                   "subkey1" : "subvalue1"
              }
}
```

If you want to update it with some new key, but you have it as a string (as you said), you need to parse it with JSON.parse(myJson).

Then add it a key/value pair :

```
myJson.key3 = "value3"; // or myJson["key3"] = "value3"
```

Now it looks like this :

```
{
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : {
                   "subkey1" : "subvalue1"
              },
     "key3" : "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate a JSON object with a new property by simply assigning a value for it, like so:

> window.universal_variable.transaction.**currency-from** = ... value ...